# Error in DetailView while trying to Post form

Tags: django, detailview

I'm running out of ideas, and tried with different solutions. I'm building for my thesis a Job Offering Page with Django 1.9. So far I built most of it, but I'm struggling trying to build the method to apply to the job.
I've ListView for the offers, Offer Page for the DetailView, but I've added a form in this one, and am getting Error 405, even when the url is redirecting to different page.

***Method Not Allowed (POST): /anuncios/display_anuncio/2/
[22/Oct/2018 09:59:00] "POST /anuncios/display_anuncio/2/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0***

In the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', crear_anuncio, name="crear_anuncio"),
url(r'^postulante_lista_anuncio/', AnuncioPostulanteList.as_view(), name="postulante_lista_anuncio"),
url(r'^postular/', postular, name='postular'),]
```

In the views.py

```
class AnuncioPostulanteList(ListView):
    model = Anuncio
    template_name = 'anuncios/postulante_lista_anuncio.html'

class DetailAnuncio(DetailView):
    model = Anuncio
    template_name = 'anuncios/pagina_anuncio.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('anuncios:pagina_anuncio')

def postular(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostularForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.fecha_postulacion = timezone.now()
            instance.id_usuario_postulante = request.request.user.pk
            instance.id_anuncio = request.id_anuncio
            instance.fecha_cambio_postulacion = timezone.now()
            instance.save()
            return redirect('anuncios:postulante_lista_anuncio') 
    else:
        form = PostularForm()
    return render(request, 'anuncios/postulante_lista_anuncio.html', 
                  {'form': form})
```

In the forms.py (Just in Case)

```
class PostularForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Postulacion
        fields = [
        'id_postulacion',
        'fecha_postulacion',
        'id_usuario_postulante',
        'id_anuncio',
        'id_estado_postulacion',
        'fecha_cambio_postulacion',
        ]
```

And finally in the pagina_anuncio.html

```
{% extends 'anuncios/base_anuncio_postulante.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}


{% block content %}

<!-- Page Content
================================================== -->
<div class="dashboard-content-container" data-simplebar>
    <div class="dashboard-content-inner" >
        <div class="single-page-header" data-background-image="{% static "images/single-job.jpg" %}">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <form method="post"> 
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="single-page-header-inner">
                            <div class="left-side">
                                <div class="header-image"><a href="single-company-profile.html"><img src="{% static "images/company-logo-03a.png" %}" alt=""></a></div>
                                <div class="header-details">
                                    <h3>{{ anuncio.titulo_anuncio }}</h3>
                                    <h4>{{ anuncio.alter_titulo_anuncio }}</h4>
                                    <h5> Acerca del Empleador</h5>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li></li><i class="icon-material-outline-business"></i> {{ anuncio.user_ptr_id }} </li>
                                        <li><img class="flag" src="images/flags/gb.svg" alt=""> {{ anuncio.id_direccion }} </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right-side">
                                <div class="salary-box">
                                    <div class="salary-type">Salario</div>
                                    <div class="salary-amount">$ {{ anuncio.salario }}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <!-- Content -->
            <div class="col-md-8 content-right-offset">
                <div class="single-page-section">
                    <h3 class="margin-bottom-25">Descripción</h3>
                    <p>{{ anuncio.detalle_anuncio }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="single-page-section">
                    <h3 class="margin-bottom-25">Descripción Alternativa</h3>
                    <p>{{ anuncio.alter_detalle_anuncio }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
                <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="sidebar-container">
                    <button type="submit" class="apply-now-button"> Postular Ahora <i class="icon-material-outline-arrow-right-alt"></i></button>
                    <!-- Sidebar Widget -->
                    <div class="sidebar-widget">
                        <div class="job-overview">
                            <div class="job-overview-headline"> Resumen del Trabajo </div>
                            <div class="job-overview-inner">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <i class="icon-material-outline-location-on"></i>
                                        <span> Dirección </span>
                                        <h5> {{ anuncio.id_direccion }} </h5>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <i class="icon-material-outline-business-center"></i>
                                        <span>Tipo de Trabajo</span>
                                        <h5>{{ anuncio.tipo_trabajo }}</h5>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <i class="icon-material-outline-local-atm"></i>
                                        <span>Salario</span>
                                        <h5>{{ anuncio.salario }}</h5>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <i class="icon-material-outline-access-time"></i>
                                        <span>Posteado hace:</span>
                                        <h5>2 days ago</h5>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Sidebar Widget -->
                    <div class="sidebar-widget">
                        <h3>Compártelo</h3>
                        <!-- Copy URL -->
                        <div class="copy-url">
                            <input id="copy-url" type="text" value="" class="with-border">
                            <button class="copy-url-button ripple-effect" data-clipboard-target="#copy-url" title="Copy to Clipboard" data-tippy-placement="top"><i class="icon-material-outline-file-copy"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Where is  this url "/anuncios/display_anuncio/2/" in your urls.py? or where it coming from

Comment: But the URL *isn't* pointing to a different page. You don't have a URL in your form in the template at all.

Comment: I've forgotten to add "display_anuncio" url, now is added. I've just added relevant urls and skipped that one for a mistake.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, sorry, am kinda new to Django, are you referring to an action in the form, am asking because I didn't added it before in the other pages that contained forms....

Comment: But now you want to post the form to a different view (postular) from the one which rendered it in the first place (DetailAnuncio). So of course you need to put that URL in template so the browser knows where to post to.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks a lot, it seems that something that simple was killing me :(